# Y86 Architecture Immediate VS Register Arithmetic Efficiency Question

Tags: performance, assembly, micro-optimization, y86, immediate-operand

I am working with a team in a Computer Architecture class on a Y86 program to implement multiplication function imul. We have a block of code that works, but we are trying to make it as execution-time efficient as we can. Currently our block looks like this for imul:

```
imul:
    # push all used registers to stack for preservation
    pushq %rdi
    pushq %rsi
    pushq %r8
    pushq %r9
    pushq %r10
    
    irmovq 0, %r9       # set 0 into r9
    rrmovq %rdi, %r10   # preserve rdi in r10
    subq %rsi, %rdi     # compare rdi and rsi
    rrmovq %r10, %rdi   # restore rdi
    jl continue         # if rdi (looping value/count) less than rsi, don't swap
    
swap:
    # swap rsi and rdi to make rdi smaller value of the two
    rrmovq %rsi, %rdi
    rrmovq %r10, %rsi
    
continue: 
    subq %r9, %rdi      # check if rdi is zero
    cmove %r9, %rax     # if rdi = 0, rax = 0
    je imulDone         # if rdi = 0, jump to end
    irmovq 1, %r8       # set 1 into r8
    rrmovq %rsi, %rax   # set rax equal to initial value from rsi
    
imulLoop:
    subq %r8, %rdi      # count - 1
    je imulDone         # if count = 0, jump to end
    addq %rsi, %rax     # add another instance of rsi into rax, looped adition
    jmp imulLoop        # restart loop
    
imulDone:
    # pop all used registers from stack to original values and return 
    popq %r10
    popq %r9
    popq %r8
    popq %rsi
    popq %rdi
    ret
```

Right now our best idea is using immediate arithmetic instructions (isubq, etc) instead of normal OPq instructions with settings constants into registers and using those registers. **Would this method be meaningfully more efficient in this particular instance?** Thanks so much!

Comment: Y86 is a teaching language, not a real machine, is it not?  So how does anyone know which is faster?  I guess you can benchmark it in your emulator, but all emulators may not be alike.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is a teaching language, a "simplified" if you want to call it that, more like dumbed down version of x86. I suppose the premise I'm after is if (in general, if it can even be said), immediate arithmetic is "more efficient" than saving a constant to a register and using register-to-register arithmetic. I know a lot can affect this, I'm just curious if, in general with assembly code, it is better practice for execution time.

Comment: Does your y86 even have `isubq` in the first place?  Most y86-64 instruction lists I've seen only provide  reg-reg forms of ALU instructions.  e.g. https://w3.cs.jmu.edu/lam2mo/cs261_2018_08/files/y86-isa.pdf (which interestingly also shows microarchitectural effects for each insn in a 5-stage classic-RISC pipeline; immediate and register instructions would have identical costs just like in mainstream x86 CPUs, assuming no front-end decode stalls due to larger instructions that include an immediate.)

Comment: @PeterCordes We are using a version of y86 that does have immediate arithmetic/iOPq instructions. I'm not sure if some versions of y86 don't include them, but our textbook talks about them and we've learned about them many times in class, much like x86 or (if I remember right, it was 2+ years ago now that I learned about it) MIPS. To write this code, my team is using a web-based y86 simulator found here: https://boginw.github.io/js-y86-64/ and this simulator does allow immediate-value instructions. I have shortened the above code a lot since posting, and using immediate arithmetic has worked.